# Псевдокласс active в js

Tags: javascript, css

У меня меню, и в нем при нажатий на определенный блок он становится активным, но при нажатий на следующий тот должен перестать быть активным. Я написала все как в примере, но почему то они продолжают стоять в активном состояний.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div[id^=block]').hide();

    $('li.view').click(function(){
        $('ul.Mynav>li:not(li.view)').**removeClass**('active');
        $(this).**addClass**('active');
        $('div#block1').fadeIn(200);
        $('div[id^=block]:not(div#block1)').fadeOut(200);
    });

    $('li.company').click(function(){
        $('ul.Mynav>li:not(li.company)').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('div#block2').fadeIn(200);
        $('div[id^=block]:not(div#block2)').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
    background-color:#3399ff;
}
```

перепроверила несколько раз...( 
в видео по которому делала сайт сказано что **add** добавляет а **remove** отключает(что то вроде), но не работает.
https://jsfiddle.net/acac2c7n/ Вот.

Comment: Шаг №1. Привести самодостаточный код, чтобы было понятно, что вообще происходит (где HTML? что за выделения звёздочками в коде?). Шаг №2. Выкинуть видео, если оно учит писать такой код. Жуткий лапшекод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, звездочки тут `.**removeClass**(` и тут `.**addClass**(` определенно лишние.
`$('ul.Mynav>li:not(li.company)').removeClass('active');` - уберет класс `active` со всех пунктов твоего меню кроме тех, которые класса `company`.
Т.е. если таких несколько, то при переключении между ними они будут оставаться в состоянии `active`.
[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/pjej7o2m/74/) рабочий пример.

Comment: спасибо, я просто слишком много понаписала смотря на тот пример.